In Paginated Report Builder, how do I make the parameters to automatically select "Select All" so the user doesn't need to?
I have a Paginated Report that I built and I need help having the drop downs to be select all by default so the user doesn't need to go in and click on "Select All". Additionally, I have a date dropdown, right now it's sorting ascending, how do I change it to sort descending so the latest date is at the top?
For background, my report is connected to a Power BI semantic model...I have two datasets, one for calendar where the date is coming from and one called Employee that the rest of the data is coming from. I'm not doing an embedded paginated report into a Power BI report, it's just a direct Paginated Report published to the Power BI service. Thanks for the help

set the default values to the same query/dataset as the available values

@AlanSchofield thank you, but unfortunately I've tried that already and still requires me to make a selection before going to next parameter

It might be because it's driven from a semantic model rather than plain sql queries. With plain sql datasets queries, this definitely does work, even with cascading parameters.
